# Binding popup PlacementTarget to listbox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, popup

I have the following XAML (simplified):

```
<Grid>
        <Popup Name="Popup" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=GameWheel, Path=SelectedItem}" PlacementTarget="{Binding SelectedItem}" Placement="Center" IsOpen="True">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="100" />
        </Popup>

        <DockPanel Margin="40,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="GameWheel"  ...>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <c:VirtualizingWrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image x:Name="GamesWheelImage" ... />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

While the DataContext is correct and it shows me the right image in the popup, the placement is completely wrong. My intention is to have the popup cover the center of the SelectedItem in the listbox, but for some reason it's always placed in the center of the window.

Any ideas on how to get the placement for the selectedItem in the listbox so the popup always covers the center of the selected item? The closest I get it to place the image in the center of the listbox, but I'm not able to get it to cover just the selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should create a specific template for the ListBoxItems which belong to the Listbox called *GameWheel*.
Just to give you a sample, I created a simplier version of your ListBox:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemWithPopup" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Border Name="border" Padding="2">
                <Grid>
                    <Popup Name="popup" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                           Placement="Center" >
                        <TextBlock Margin="1" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Popup>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="popup" Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Azure" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <DockPanel Margin="40,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="GameWheel">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemWithPopup}" />
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.Items>
                    <sys:String>One</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Four</sys:String>
                </ListBox.Items>
            </ListBox>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

As you can see the `Popup` is directly contained in the `ListBoxItem` template and it is showed using a Trigger.
I hope my sample can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me an idea on how to fix it. The first item is now as I want it, but selecting another item will crash the application with the following error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` thrown by VirtualizingWrapPanel.cs. By this code: `(next as UIElement).Focus();` I don't thought that this would modify the collection in any way....

Comment: It is not easy to understand the reason or your exception @NeoID, since I do not know how your VirtualizingWrapPanel is implemented. Probably you should edit your question and adding new details, or maybe you would ask a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Thank you for getting me on the right track at least. :)